# Need Help in Case Output (BASH)

Tags: bash

I have a simple case that says like

```
case "$1" in
    -b*) myfunction exit 0;;
    -B*) echo "Invalid!" >&2 exit 1;;
esac
```

What I **want** is basically when user input argument using "**b**", it will do some stuff from myfunction. Else, if user input using "**B**", it will print error and exit the program.

However, what really happens is that when user input "**B**", it prints

```
Invalid! exit 1
```

instead of

```
Invalid!
```

Also, it gives an exit value of "**0**" instead of "**1**". Does anybody know which part did I do it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace in your script

```
echo "Invalid!" >&2 exit 1
```

by

```
echo "Invalid!" >&2; exit 1
```

Comment: I have questions regarding the exit. So when it reads "exit 1", does it go out of the case loop or completely go to the really bottom of the script line?

Comment: `exit 1` quits your script immediately with return code 1.